# How to copy code when compiling a gradle library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an Android library for phones and watches. While some of the code is the same, I do need two separate modules to store watch code and phone code.

I built the library and uploaded it to Maven without issue. I can import these libraries into separate projects without issue.

`compile 'com.github.fleker:my-library:1.0.0'`

`compile 'com.github.fleker:my-library-wear:1.0.0'`

However, I'd like to reduce the amount of code being copied and pasted by having a third module in my library that stores all the shared code. In this `my-library-common` module, I store a handful of classes and then add this library to each `build.gradle`.

`compile project(':my-library-common')`

This seems to work in my library's project. However, when I upload this project and try downloading it somewhere else, I run into errors when doing a Gradle sync:

`Failed to Resolve: SettingsManager:settingsmanager:undefined`
`Failed to Resolve: SettingsManager:library-common:undefined`

So I realize my mistake. When I'm compiling the project, my phone and wear modules are compiling from a known location. However, it isn't importing the code, only pointing to it. When I go to a separate project, that pointer is invalid.

Is there a way that I can force the `library-common` module to import its code into my two main modules so that I can have a single module for some code but have two other separate modules as my actual libraries?

Maybe, instead of `compile project(':my-library-common')` there is some sort of `import project(':my-library-common')` which will place the code into the project so that when I upload this library the `my-library-common` code is included.

Does this make sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Product Flavours ( or technically Build Variants) feature provided by gradle.

***Define product flavors in the build file***

```
...
android {
...
  defaultConfig { ... }
  signingConfigs { ... }
  buildTypes { ... }
  productFlavors {
    main {
        applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.main"
        versionName "1.0"
     }
    my-library {
        applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.lib"
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    my-library-wear {
        applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.lib-wear"
        versionName "1.0"
     }
   }
 }
...
```

1. Gradle sync.
2. Create specific folder defined as your product flavours under your package name i.e com.buildsystemexample
3. So you would basically be having 3 folders under the above mentioned package : main, lib, lib-wear
4. Put the common code under the main module.
5. Put the other code under their respective module. i.e lib and lib-wear.
6. From your BuildVariant tab ( bottom left in android studio) you can choose your build variant.
7. You can compile one type of lib at a time by choosing the specific build variant in the tab.

Ref: [android official docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I'm trying to understand how this would work in my case. Right now I'm using top-level modules whereas you're referring to build variants.

My libraries aren't being packaged and then uploaded. They're being uploaded to Gradle via Sonatype with a maven-push.gradle script: https://medium.com/android-news/the-complete-guide-to-creating-an-android-library-46628b7fc879#.abju1ozbm

What I think I can do as a workaround is push my common code library to Maven and then include that in my public libraries instead of compiling the project directly.

Comment: @Nick using transitive dependencies is very much recommended. But even if you are doing a maven push via gradle this should work. Most of the docs talks about product flavours with respect to application,  but it works with library code too. Only thing that changes is your usual build. gradle which basically checks which flavour is selected at a time and pushes the aar file to maven central at a time.

Comment: I got around to trying to implement product flavors in my build file. However, as this is a library and not a standard app, I've been running into an error with setting flavors' application ids. I'm not sure if it is possible to have multiple variants of a library in this way.